# Issue with keyCode Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out if the entered strings start with a double quotation mark (") or not. Depending on this, it should trigger keys.

If the string begins with a quotation mark, a triggerEvent "Enter / return" should automatically follow after the second quotation mark. The space-key may be pressed up to the second quotation mark without any impact or event.

If the string begins not with a quotation mark, every time the user presses space, the key event for "Enter / return" should be triggered.

Everything works fine until the user enters a string without quotation marks. Then, after entering a string with a starting quotation mark immediately after the space key, the event Enter / Return is triggered.

What is the issue? Thank you so much for your tips!

```
$('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').on('input', function(e) {
curString = '';
curString = $(this).val();
curLength = curString.length;
matchQuote = curString.match('^"');

// begins with a quotation mark" //
if (matchQuote) {
    console.log('begins with quote');
    $('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
            console.log('begins with a quotation mark, (space) pressed');
        }
    });
    if (curLength > 1) {
        if (curString.match('"$')) {
            var event = jQuery.Event('keydown');
            event.which = 13;
            event.keyCode = 13;
            jQuery('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').trigger(event);
        }
    }
};

// begins not with a quotation mark" //
if (!matchQuote) {
    console.log('beginnt  nicht mit "');
    $('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
            console.log('begins not with a quotation mark, (space) pressed"');
            var event = jQuery.Event('keydown');
            event.which = 13;
            event.keyCode = 13;
            jQuery('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').trigger(event);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        };
    });
};
});
```

Thank you Dymos, now it works:

```
$('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').keydown(function(e) {
curString = '';
curString = $('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').val();
curLength = curString.length;
matchQuote = curString.match('^"');
// begins with a quotation mark" //
if (matchQuote) {
    if (curLength > 1) {
        if (curString.match('"$')) {
            var event = jQuery.Event('keydown');
            event.which = 13;
            event.keyCode = 13;
            jQuery('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').trigger(event);         
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
};

if (!matchQuote) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
            var event = jQuery.Event('keydown');
            event.which = 13;
            event.keyCode = 13;
            jQuery('#inlineFilters-tokenfield').trigger(event);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;   
        };
};  
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating an event handler for `keydown` in your `input` event handler. You probably want your main event to be `keydown` and then you can refactor this do not create nested event handlers.

Comment: you mean nested within my input?

Comment: thank you Dymos, now it works!!!